# Sql Server 2008 .NET Administration API

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there an API that has built in functions/methods to manage a SQL Server Host?

You could just connect as sysadmin and execute the sql commands, but i think there is something out-of-the-box for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is SMO (SQL Management Objects). It is the API for managing SQL through managed code.  Have a look at this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Microsoft's PowerShell. I suspect it is what you're after.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx

Comment: Powershell is excellent for this, but even its built in command-lets for SQL Server are really just calling the SMOs. So it is good to have a handle on them as well.

Answer (score -1):

No, SQL Server interface is SQL Language. There are some Object models, but nothng .NET specific.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa274764(SQL.80).aspx for the administration objects.

Comment: TomTom, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Objects